# T-shirt simulation; sharp pinches around the hem

Tags: cloth-simulation

I made this hem around the edges but as you can see it creates very sharp pinch around in my render when i simulate it. Does anyone know how i can fix this not to happen before simluating? I have to animate the simulation so fixing the vertices afterwords wont make sense in my case. cheers!
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/